# python recursive regex optimization

Tags: python, performance, regex

I parse a big source code directory (100k files). I traverse every line in every file and look for function calls via regex matching.

I know that using regex to parse languages is a terrible idea. However, I'm looking for simplicity and not interested in the whole parse tree. Moreover, the regex pattern is generic and applies to all languages with the `func(arg)` syntax.

Following some profiling that I did, my hotspot is of course the function that responsible of processing a single line and search matches in that line. In big code projects, this function is called about 25 million times.
I was wondering weather there is room for optimization in the following 9 lines, or is this as good as it gets:

```
def get_line_symbols(self, line):
    symbols = []
    matches = self.index_pattern.finditer(line)
    for match in matches:
        while match:
            symbols.append(match.group(1))
            symbol_args = match.group(2)
            match = self.index_pattern.search(symbol_args)
    return symbols
```

`self.index_pattern` is `re.compile('(\w+)(\([^\)]*\)?)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can improve the performance by 25% or so, by stopping the regular expression after the opening parenthesis, and so avoiding the need for a `while` loop or indeed a function at all:

```
get_line_symbols = re.compile(r'(\w+)\(').findall
```

(Note that it's a good idea to use the `r` modifier on regular expression strings, to avoid the risk of accidentally writing something like `'\b'`, which needs to be written as `r'\b'` or `'\\b'` if it's to mean a word boundary rather than the backspace character.)

I get a further speedup by switching from the built-in `re` library to the third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) library. Using both of these improvements is about three times as fast as the code in the post.

Comment: the while loop is used to handle a line with nested function calls, f(g(h)). In this case, you need to regex the arguments until there's no match.

Comment: @susdu Your original regex attempts to look for matching pairs of parentheses, but it actually doesn't.  For `f(g(h))`, the first match would be `f(g(h)` — note that the closing parenthesis is dropped.  Since regular expressions are no good at identifying nested matching pairs, you would be better off just looking for the opening parenthesis.

Comment: @200_success is quite right — the complicated regex in the question isn't finding any more matches than the simple regex in the answer. Try it out and see for yourself!

Comment: I guess I really over-complicated this, thanks guys